# What are typical CLmaxTO and CLmaxL values for modern aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design

Roskam gives these values for typical ranges:

[image]

However several of his tables are off (for example he estimates typical cruising L/D at 13-15 when many planes are above that). Does anyone know typical values for modern aircraft? For example, I'm guessing that values of 2.35-2.5 for takeoff and 3.2+ for landing might not be uncommon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following additional references.

1. **Torenbeek chapter 7**

[image]

Not a very new document, granted. But the list contains several jet transports with a $C_{Lmax}$ in landing of about 3 or over:

- DC9-30 @ 2.98
- B737-200 @ 3.05
- BAC Three-Eleven @ 3.19
- DC10-30 @ 2.98

2. **2018 Sesar paper.**. [Linked article here](https://www.sesarju.eu/sites/default/files/documents/sid/2018/papers/SIDs_2018_paper_75.pdf), provided by @ymb1.

[image]

The table contains a computed value of $C_{Lmax}$ of the aeroplane in landing, based on dimensional data and published data.

The only thing to figure out now is which modern jet transports use triple slotted Fowler flaps with slats. In general, this won't be the case for shortened versions like the A319 and B737-700.

As mentioned in [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/48466/21091), usually the longer/shorter versions all share the same wing, and only differ in length of the fuselage plugs. This means that the shorter versions have a lower wing loading, and don't need all the sophisticated flaps & slats to get airborne. As also mentioned in the [question on B747SP flaps](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45392/21091).

[image]

Comment: Funny table - "Flower" should read "Fowler".